# Accidently deleted my OSX "login" keychain

Tags: macos, keychain

I think I messed up - I am fairly new to OSX and accidently deleted my "login" keychain. (I actually just wanted to delete a certificate I had just created but oh well.)

This also means I lost my xcode certificates I use for iOS development. (But I believe these can be redownloaded and installed without any problems.) I recall there also was an Apple certificate lasting to mid 2016 which I do not believe was related to anything development.

What is the proper way to restore/rebuild a working "login" keychain. Currently Safari is asking for password everytime I try browse a website :) I am wondering if I need to do anything special to begin with to avoid later problems.

Comment: Do you have backups?